# How to write script for arithmetic mean of even numbers

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, command

I have to write a script in bash where I have to provide 10 numbers to the table. Then script have to write the content out and arithmetic mean of even numbers. I did like 90% of the script, but I can't find out how to extract information about quantity of even numbers that is needed for arithmetic mean.

Here is my code:

```
echo "Provide data:"
i=0
for (( i = 0 ; i < 10; i++ ))
do
echo "Provide $[$i+1] number:"
read x
if [ "$x" = "" ]
then
 break
else
 table[$i]=$x
fi

done

echo "Provided data: ${table[*]}" 


result=0


for (( i = 0 ; i < 10; i++))
do
 res=$[${table[i]}%2]

 if [ $res -eq 0 ]
 then
 echo "Number ${table[i]} is even"
 result=$[$result+${table[$i]}]
 fi
done

echo "SUM:$[$result]"
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I don't know if I understood you correctly but for example Input: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 Output:  Arithemtic mean = 2+4+6+8+10 = 30 / 5 = 6

Comment: They meant to edit that into the question. Many people don't read comments to look for the question/example.

Answer (score 0):

ignoring data input  adding only odd inputs can look like :

```
$ cat c.sh
 
#!/bin/bash
declare -A xDarray
sum=0 
xDarray[0 1]=1
xDarray[0 2]=3
xDarray[1 0]=2
xDarray[2 0]=4
 
 
for var in ${xDarray[@]}
do
        if [ $(( $var & 1 )) == 0 ] ; then
                echo $var is even
                i+=1
                tab[$i]=$var
                sum=$(( $sum + $var))
        fi
done

var=$(echo ${tab[@]} | sed 's/ / + /g' )
echo $var = $sum
```

result in

```
$ ./c.sh
2 is even
4 is even
2 + 4 = 6
$
```

whatever the number of data is used it would work
I let you work around your data input

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggested modifications for your script, syntax is simple.

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=()

for (( i=1;i<=10;i++ )); do
    number=''
    while [[ ! $number =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; do
        printf "Please enter number $i:\n"
        read number
    done
    arr+=($number)
done

printf "\nProvided numbers:"
printf " %d" "${arr[@]}" 
printf "\nEven numbers:"

s=0
n=0
for x in "${arr[@]}"; do
    if ! (( x % 2 )); then
        printf " %d" "$x"
        s=$(( s + x ))
        (( n++ ))
    fi
done

m=$(( s / n ))
printf "\nMean of the %d even numbers: %d / %d = %d\n" "$n" "$s" "$n" "$m"
```

Use an array `arr` to hold the input numbers, declare with `arr=()`, append numbers with `arr+=($x)`, we refer only `${arr[@]}` for all the items and we avoid any other complex array references, indices etc.

Every input `number` is tested against [regular expression](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_01.html) `^[0-9]+$` which means one or more digits (and only digits) with the `=~` operator, and if this is not true, we prompt again for the same `i-th` input number.

Also we prefer [`printf`](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) for printing.

The last loop is the standard array loop, where we use again the [arithmetic expansion](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) syntax to find the even numbers, to add them to the sum and get the mean of them (result is an integer).

If you want to print a decimal result, e.g. with 2 floating points, you could use `bc` and `printf "%f"` like this:

```
m=$( bc <<< "scale=2; $s/$n" )
printf "%.2f" "$m"
```